# NHibernate in Action book

Tags: nhibernate

I am searching for a good book on NHibernate and sorted out that 'NHibernate in Action' should be good for me.

I am currently working on a project that uses Fluent NHibernate but still would like to dive into how-it-works basics.
Wondering if there is any newer release of NHibernate in Action book other than which explains Version 1.2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Get a copy of the [NHibernate 3.0 Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/nhibernate-3-0-cookbook/book)

Comment: I have the book and I have used it profusely. Highly recommended.